# Convert UUID to/from binary in Node

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

The project I work on switched to MySQL. The keys we use are UUID strings (like 43d597d7-2323-325a-90fc-21fa5947b9f3), but the database field, rather than be a string, is defined as binary(16) - 16-byte unsigned binary.

I understand that a UUID is basically a 16-byte binary, but I have no idea how to convert from/to a binary number.

I'm using [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) to access the database, and I tried using [node-uuid](https://github.com/shtylman/node-uuid) to parse the UUID, but that yields an array of integers. I also tried using [Node's Buffer](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html), but that just yields a buffer object.

How do I convert a UUID string to fit into that field? And how do I turn a value I read from that field into a UUID?

Comment: The [`HEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_hex) function should get you pretty close.

Comment: the array of integers you mention might be what you want, after you convert them back to a string using n .toString(16)

Comment: @dandavis the first thing I tried was: remove dashes from x, `y = parseInt(x, 16)` -> yields a large number (like 9.2230...e+31), but then `y.toString(16)` returns a completely different number. JavaScript cannot handle a 16 byte precision well, and is probably losing significant digits in the conversion.

Comment: How does the array of integers look like after conversion?

Comment: the ranges in dashes are of different byte sizes: 4-2-2-2-6 (16 total), you can't parse them as one big number because js numbers don't have that many bytes... see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier for details

Comment: Assuming that the array of numbers `nums` that you received from `node-uuid` contains valid info, using `var uuid = (nums.map(function(nbr){ return nbr.toString(16); })).join('-');` should give you the UUID representation you're looking for. I typed this without testing so it's probably not copy/paste safe.

Comment: @N.B. this does not solve the main issue which is having a number to put in the DB. node-uuid returns `[ 67, 213, 151, 215, 35, 35, 50, 90, 144, 252, 33, 250, 89, 71, 185, 243 ]` for `'43d597d7-2323-325a-90fc-21fa5947b9f3'` - how do I put this in the database? What do I read back?

Comment: I see, it gives you each byte converted to integer (decimal). If you count the bytes of the UUID you showed us (two "letters" which represent hexadecimal notation = 1 byte), you can see there's 16 of them. Remove the dash, you'll get exactly 16 bytes in hex (32 characters). Now, as for what it is - 43d597d7 is this: [43 = 67, d5 = 213, 97 = 151, d7 = 215]. Applying the same logic to the rest, you get the method for converting to string representation of UUID from integers. Does that clear it up a bit?

Comment: After checking the node-uuid - it gives you methods `parse` and `unparse` which converts the uuid back and forth. Have you tried them?

Comment: Yes, I have - the array is the result of `.parse()`. I know those are integers. Again, I need one big number to send to the db, and a way to parse such a number when it comes back. I doubt I can send an array to the db, or accept one back.

Comment: Yes, the array is the result of .parse, and if you use `var string = uuid.unparse(the_array_you_just_got);` - you get the UUID in the "string" format. That's getting it out. The other question is - are you using javascript to actually generate UUIDs? If yes, is there any chance you would let MySQL do it instead?

Comment: I'm not using JS to create the UUIDs. Node is only used as a REST provider, getting UUIDs as parameter, putting them in the DB, pulling them out and returning. So: got UUID as string->used `parse`->got array of ints->.....? what do I send to MySQL? Similarly, got value from MySQL->how do I turn into an array of ints so I can `unparse`? There are steps missing here.

Comment: Right, if you have a UUID `43d597d7-2323-325a-90fc-21fa5947b9f3` in that string format already in your JS app, you'd send the following query to MySQL: `SELECT col FROM table WHERE uuid_col = UNHEX(REPLACE('43d597d7-2323-325a-90fc-21fa5947b9f3', '-', ''));`. If you want to pull data out and have UUID in readable format, you have to convert it to hexadecimal notation. `SELECT HEX(uuid_col) FROM table;` -> that one will give you the UUID without dashes. It *appears* that the node-uuid.parse method works if you give it hex string without dashes.

Comment: @N.B. You did it! The last 2 worked! Please submit your comment as an answer so I can mark it as the correct one. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Due to lack of time, I'll paste the comment that provided valid result(s) and modify the answer later so it's clearer.

---

Right, if you have a `UUID 43d597d7-2323-325a-90fc-21fa5947b9f3` in that string format already in your JS app, you'd send the following query to MySQL:

`SELECT col FROM table WHERE uuid_col = UNHEX(REPLACE('43d597d7-2323-325a-90fc-21fa5947b9f3', '-', ''));`

If you want to pull data out and have UUID in readable format, you have to convert it to hexadecimal notation.

`SELECT HEX(uuid_col) FROM table;`

That one will give you the UUID without dashes. It appears that the `node-uuid.parse` method works if you give it hex string without dashes.

Comment: What node module is this. Is this one you are referring https://github.com/kelektiv/node-uuid ? It does not have a parse method.

Comment: @MustafaMamun [I'm referring to the module that OP mentioned in his question](https://github.com/defunctzombie/node-uuid)

Answer (score 3):

While N.B.'s answer works I stumbled upon another solution.

UUID v1 starts with character segments that are time based; however, the smallest units come first making distribution rather scattered in an index.

If you aren't stuck on the precise UUID v1 format than there is a NodeJS module that can generate unique IDs based on UUID v1 that also monotonically increase and scale about as well as auto incremented IDs. It also works with node-mysql.

Checkout: [monotonic-id](https://github.com/gregl83/monotonic-id)

An example with node-mysql:

```
var MID = require('monotonic-id');

var mid = new MID();

client.query('INSERT INTO `...` SET `mid`=?', mid.toBuffer(), function(err, res) {
   ...
})
```