# How to seed array of UUIDs with Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a model with a column `users` whose type is `DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.UUID)`.

In my seed script, I am applying

```
await queryInterface.bulkInsert('MyTable', [
  {
    id: uuid4(),
    users: [uuid4(), uuid4()]
  }
])
```

However, the seeding fails with `ERROR: column "users" is of type uuid[] but expression is of type text[]`.

How do I make Sequelize recognize this is an array of UUIDs?

Comment: have you tried to pass them as binary? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753505/convert-uuid-to-from-binary-in-node

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sequelize's literals to solve this, replacing `users` with:

```
users: Sequelize.literal(`ARRAY['${uuid4()}', '${uuid4()}']::uuid[]`)
```

where `Sequelize` is the main class for the Node.js library.

[Here are other solutions for `ARRAY(ENUM)`.](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/11541)